# How to target specific audience in FCM UI?

Tags: push-notification

We want to use cloud messaging to deliver message to specific audience - people who last opened our app exactly 2 days ago.

In the FCM interface we see 3 parameters:

- more than x days ago
- less than x day ago
- from x to y days ago

What should we use to target audience who last opened our app exactly 2 days ago?

Comment: Can you use the last option where x and y are both 2? Or perhaps between 2 and 3 days? It depends how those options are calculated, but you probably want to check if it's a rolling x days, or if that is from 00:00 to 23:59, for instance. Also timezones!

Comment: We tried it but no audience returned. If we chose 2 and 6 day then appeared something